# "Reinstalling" /usr and /local folder

Tags: macos

How would I be able to reinstall Yosemite keeping the software I've installed through things like brew or macports but not the "system" files? For example, the system files being /System, /usr, /bin, /Library and such.

I think that I might have to backup my personal files then do a full system wipe and then move everything back over. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upgrade OS X the installer preserves the things that you've installed to `/usr/local` (through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)) and `/opt` (through [MacPorts](http://macports.org)). Always a good idea to have backups though, just in case.

It has been suggested that you might want to temporarily move the contents of `/usr/local` to speed up the install though. [Faster Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite Upgrades for Developers](https://jimlindley.com/blog/yosemite-upgrade-homebrew-tips/)